# Using ajax to check radiobutton by Id in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I saw a code that checks the radio button by value, but how do I do this by id? My current scenario is that I'm populating a table by appending html codes using ajax. I'm looping the prices of a certain item while building the html table. After that, I need to check the radio button of a price where default flag is equal to 'Y'.

Here's my if statement that checks the radiobutton by value only, this is not working yet as my radiobutton values are null, only the id and name has value:

```
if (item.defaultflag == 'Y')
    $('#divItemPrice').find(':radio[name=rbDefaultPrice][value="iPrice_' + item.channelid + '"]').prop('checked', true);
else
    $('#divItemPrice').find(':radio[name=rbDefaultPrice][value="iPrice_' + item.channelid + '"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Complete code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Item/RetrievePrice',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        var trHTML = "";
        debugger;
        trHTML = '<tbody id="dbBody2">';
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            trHTML += '<tr><td class="hidden">' + item.itemid + '</td>' +
                      '<td style="width:20px"><label><input type="radio" name="rbDefaultPrice" id = "iPrice_' + item.itemid + '" /></label></td>' +
                      '<td>' + item.itemprice + '</td>' +
                      '<td>' + ToJavaScriptDate(item.startdate) + '</td>' +
                      '<td>' + ToJavaScriptDate(item.enddate) + '</td>' +
                      '</tr>';

            //How do I check the radiobutton by id?
            if (item.defaultflag == 'Y')
                $('#divItemPrice').find(':radio[name=rbDefaultPrice][value="iPrice_' + item.itemid + '"]').prop('checked', true);
            else
                $('#divItemPrice').find(':radio[name=rbDefaultPrice][value="iPrice_' + item.itemid + '"]').prop('checked', false);
        });

        trHTML += '</tbody>';
        $("#tblItemPrice tbody").remove();
        $('#tblItemPrice').append(trHTML);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Error! " + xhr.status);
    }
});
```

View (modal part)

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="divItemPrice" class="" style="border: 0px solid green; ">
            <table id="tblItemPrice" onclick="gettabledata('tblItemPrice', '0,2,3,4', 'itemPriceId,itemPrice,strtDt,endDt')" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped bootgrid-table" aria-busy="false" padding-left:10px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="inner-table-head">
                        <th class="hidden">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.itemPriceId)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Price
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Start Date
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            End Date
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="bodyToAppend">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row form-row">
                <span class="form-item">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.itemPriceId)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.itemPrice, new { @class = "lbl-width" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.itemPrice, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-row">
                <span class="form-item ">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.strtDt, new { @class = "lbl-width" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.strtDt, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @Value = "" })
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-row">
                <span class="form-item ">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.endDt, new { @class = "lbl-width" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.endDt, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @Value = "" })
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-row maintenance-btn">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSavePrice" value="Save" class="btn btn-theme btn-sm" formmethod="post" />
                    <input type="submit" id="btnUpdatePrice" value="Update" class="btn btn-theme btn-sm" formmethod="post" style="display:none" />
                    @*<input type="submit" id="btnCancelPrice" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-theme btn-sm" />*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="closeModal" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just set the `checked` attribute when creating it? And there is no reason for the `else` block - if you set the `checked` attribute on one radio button - it will be removed automatically from the others in the same group

Comment: And why are you not rendering a `value` attribute (your radio buttons are useless without them)

Comment: Because my first column in the table is the radiobutton and the other columns are the ones defining it already. Lke the 2nd column has the price

Comment: That's what I'm doing for every loop of <tr>. Once I created the whole row I'm checking if the default flag which my controller passed is set to True. If yes, I need to check the radio button with that particular id in the current loop

Comment: Yes but it makes no sense, what is the point of an input without a value. (and I meant set the attribute as its created, not after). And why are you adding `id` attributes?

Comment: So you mean, instead of separating the radio button and the price column I should just make it as one? I also need to make it dynamic, that's why I'm thinking of putting value on ids. But you gave me an idea, I'll try your advice. Thanks!

Comment: Its can just be (simplified) `var row = $('<tr></tr>'); var radio = $('<input type="radio" name="rbDefaultPrice"/>'); if (item.defaultflag == 'Y') { radio.prop('checked', true); } row.append($('<td></td>').html(radio));`

Comment: A cleaner and easier to understand solution would be to create a template  of a table row and clone it in each iteration and update the values/attributes.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I thought value property was the radio button's label! I just checked it. My bad. Thanks man! I'll get back to tagging this as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your `if/else` block cannot work because its attempting to `.find()` and element in the DOM which does not even exist yet (you have not added it). And even if you did add the `<tr>` to the DOM in each iteration it would result in poor performance (searching the whole table in each iteration).

A simple way to solve this (and much easier to debug the html your generating) is to create a hidden template that is cloned and added in each iteration. I also assume that you want to add the value of `itemprice` as the `value` attribute of the radio button so that you can get the value of the selected radio button using `var price = $('input[name="rbDefaultPrice"]').val();`

```
<table id="template" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="rbDefaultPrice" class="radio" />
                <span class="price"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="startdate"></td>
        <td class="enddate"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then in the `.each()` loop, clone the template, update its values and append it to the DOM

```
var tbody = $('#tblItemPrice tbody');
....
success: function (data) {
    tbody.empty() // remove existing rows
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        // clone the template row
        var row = $('#template').clone().find('tr');
        // update properties
        var radio = row.find('.radio');
        radio.val(item.itemprice);
        if (item.defaultflag == 'Y') {
            radio.prop('checked', true);
        }
        row.find('.price').text(item.itemprice);
        row.find('.startdate').text(....
        // add the row to the DOM
        tbody.append(row);
    });
}
```

Side note: Its not clear what your `ToJavaScriptDate()` function is doing, but I suggest you just pass the correctly formatted value to client so you can just use `row.find('.startdate').text(item.startdate);` etc

Comment: I've been trying to implement your answer but was unable to show the appended elements. Actually, it was in a modal that used to work (but without the check radiobutton function yet). I've updated my question to add the modal codes in View

Comment: And since I cannot make it work, I tried not to use your code `var tbody = $('#tblItemPrice tbody');`, but instead change your code `tbody.append(row)` to `$('#bodyToAppend').append(row);`, which is the id of tblItemPrice tbody. But it still doesn't show the appended rows :(

Comment: I also tried to change `.text` to `.val`, but it doesn't work

Comment: @HarambeAttackHelicopter, I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87qfLp2r/1/) to show you how it works. Note I also changed `clone().children('tr');` to `clone().find('tr');` because some browsers will add the `<tbody>` tag even if you did not include it yourself

Comment: I just put this before the each `$("#tblItemPrice tr").remove();` Because when you try to click Add Date multiple times, it just increment the data and not remove the original one

Comment: Thats what `tbody.empty();` does (it removes all the existing rows inside the `<tbody>` element)